# Importing variable from text file without copying file to server

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am trying to do something like this:

```
DECLARE @MySchema VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @MySchema = BulkColumn
FROM    OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\\local\\path\\to\\MySchema.xsd', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
```

where the local path is on my machine (or, later, on the build machine -- either way, it's on the machine where the command is actually *running*) without:

1. copying MySchema.xsd to the server running SQL Server 2005,
2. creating a file share on the local box,
3. assuming that the local box will be running SQL Server, or
4. using anything other than T-SQL to perform the task.

Is this possible?  If so, how can it be done?  If it matters, this is going to be part of an automated build/deployment procedure that will create an XML schema collection on the SQL Server instance.

Comment: @marc_s Thanks.  I think that qualifies as an answer, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

If you want to import something into SQL Server, it has to be on that SQL Server machine; or at least on a disk that's accessible to the SQL Server machine via an UNC path over the network.